# angular netcore app redirects to /index.html instead of /

Tags: angular, redirect, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an Angular 7 + Asp.Net Core 2.2 website.

When users enter the url: `domain.com/` they get redirected to `domain.com/index.html`,

Then when the angular app kicks in the url goes back to `domain.com/`.

How can I prevent this jump to index.html and make it appear like this: `domain.com/` from start to the end?

The way I redirect the user to the angular app is this code in the Startup.cs class (notice I use `/` and not `/index.html`, and it still redirects to `/.index.html`):

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
    !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
    !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/") &&
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/";
        await next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you have to write custom middleware like that ? And also can you please upload full code of your startup.cs ?

Comment: @TonyNgo this custom middleware is a known approach, this way you don't need to add a route to your backend that points to your spa every time you add a route in your angular app. instead you just tell your backend that every 404 is probably a frontend route so you point the user to the spa. is there anything specific you need me to add from my startup.cs? i put the only code that is relevant, other lines of code are stuff like registering classes to the di and db context

Comment: In VS 2019 there is already a template to build ASP.Net Core & Angular app. I still dont know why you have to write this middleware

Comment: Do you use default angular/core template project?How will it  get redirected to Index.html when start the app? Do you mean you would like to redirect url which ends with`/Index.html` to `/` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#url-redirect-and-url-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not fix your issue, but I was also having the same problem. For me, it was being caused by the standard swagger generation middleware in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"{nameof(SharingService)} API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "";
});
```

This middleware causes a redirect from `/` to `/index.html` to show the swagger api.

To fix this, I added [`app.UseFileServer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#usefileserver) *before* the `app.UseSwagger()` which includes using static files and using default files.  This serves file contents *without* directing the browser first.

I also updated the swagger configuration to set `c.RoutePrefix = "api"` so that the swagger page is available at `/api` (rather than root).